# Form for populating a table does not write to next open row only to existing rows starting with 1

Tags: ms-access-2016

I am new to Access and I am working on a form that populates a table.
when I make an entry into the form it populates the table starting with the first row and overwriting the information already there.

I want the form to create a new row and add the information.

Also when I open the form it always populates with the text from the first row instead of blank.

Eventualy there will be error checking to ensure that there are no duplicate entries based on two fields.

I have searched a bit online however because I am so new I am still learning the correct vernacular.

I want the table to populate a new row every time as well as not show already entered data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the form's property *DataEntry* to: True